# reverse number that entered into input with recursion

Tags: javascript

I want to reverse number from input field, number cannot consist zero.
By button click i want to display result into div element.

I have an error in my code:

> str.substr is not a function
>       at HTMLButtonElement.reverse

What i'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="input">
    <button id="btn">Check</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
window.onload = function() {

        var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
        var str = document.getElementById("input").value;
        var result = document.getElementById("result");

        function reverse(str) {

            if (str === "0") {
                return result.innerHTML = "Number cannot consist 0";
            } else {
                  return result.innerHTML = reverse(str.substr(1)) + str.charAt(0);     
            }
        }

        btn.addEventListener("click", reverse);
    }
```

Comment: pls share your html :)

Comment: btw. the string value will only be the initial value. if you want to get the current value of the input, you will have to reassign it everytime you execute the reverse function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is you are not fetching latest value from input on button click. On pageload, the value of input is `null`. Hence it throws error.

Try this:

```js
function handleClick() {
  var str = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var result = document.getElementById("result");

  if (str.indexOf("0") >= 0) {
    result.innerHTML = "Number cannot consist 0";
  } else
    result.innerHTML = reverse(str)
}

btn.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

  function reverse(str) {
    if (str.length > 1)
      return reverse(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0)
    else
      return str
  }

  function handleClick() {
    var str = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var result = document.getElementById("result");

    if (str.indexOf("0") >=0) {
      result.innerHTML = "Number cannot consist 0";
    }
    else
      result.innerHTML = reverse(str)
  }

  btn.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text">
<div id="result"></div>

<button id="btn">Reverse</button>
```